# When I try to download StanfordNLP en model, it gives an error

Tags: python, nlp, anaconda

I am using Anaconda. First I installed **StanfordNLP** and when I execute the command

```
stanfordnlp.download('en')
```

it gives following **error**;

```
(base) C:\Users\Abdullah>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import stanfordnlp
>>> stanfordnlp.download('en')
Using the default treebank "en_ewt" for language "en".
Would you like to download the models for: en_ewt now? (Y/n)
y

Default download directory: C:\Users\Abdullah\stanfordnlp_resources
Hit enter to continue or type an alternate directory.
C:\Users\Abdullah\Downloads\New folder

Downloading models for: en_ewt
Download location: C:\Users\Abdullah\Downloads\New folder\en_ewt_models.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 257, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 368, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 257, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stanfordnlp\utils\resources.py", line 137, in download
    confirm_if_exists=confirm_if_exists, force=force, version=version)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stanfordnlp\utils\resources.py", line 101, in download_ud_model
    r = requests.get(download_url, stream=True)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

I am new to **NLP**.

Comment: as I remeber this file is very big - about 2GB - so it could take too much time to get it. Did you try to download it again ? You could also try to download it directly from web page, and uncompress to expected folder.

Comment: @furas I tried many times, but it fails. I am new to nlp, so can you help me how to download it manually from web page?

Comment: on [official page for stanfordnlp](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/) you can see information on [downloading CoreNLP and model](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) and there are links to languages.

Comment: I check Python source code for `standfordnlp` and found code which downloads model and I add `print(download_url)` to see url used to download it and it is http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanfordnlp_models/latest/en_ewt_models.zip

Comment: I found link to models on page https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/models.html#human-languages-supported-by-stanfordnlp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is problem to download with

```
import stanfordnlp
stanfordnlp.download('en')
```

Then you can download it directly from web page [StanfordNLP - Models](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/models.html#human-languages-supported-by-stanfordnlp) and unpack to the folder which you see when you use `stanfordnlp.download('en')`

On Linux I got it in folder `~/stanfordnlp_resources/en_ewt_models/` and there are files

```
 en_ewt.pretrain.pt
 en_ewt_lemmatizer.pt
 en_ewt_parser.pt
 en_ewt_tagger.pt
 en_ewt_tokenizer.pt
```

---

**BTW:** I had no problem to download it with `stanfordnlp.download()` with version `0.2.0` but I had also old version `0.1.0` and it was trying to download from different url which doesn't exist any more. They moved files to different urls on server.

```
import stanfordnlp
print(stanfordnlp.__version__)
```

Comment: thanks @furas for helping me. I try to directly download from web page using IDM. It there is same problem. It looks that it is server problem, not in the code or library.

Comment: I used a VPN and finally I am able to download this file.